# Searching an element in a 'circular sorted' 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

For the past few days I've been trying to find a way to efficiently binary search this kind of array and get it to work on any given 2d array of this kind.

Instructions:
In this question, you will refer to quadratic two-dimensional arrays, that is, the number of rows and columns is equal to the number of rows and columns equal to n. defining a split into four quarters of n/2 size as follows:
[image: Illustration of the array]

Given this kind of array, I was asked to search an element with logarithmic time complexity, and if it was found I should print the row and column of the element in the array.

Does anyone have a solution for this? A full solution would be amazing, but any answer would be appreciated.

I will share the piece of code that is very messy but this is where I got so far and it works for most of the array elements, which is not good enough since it means whole logic is wrong.

```
int[][] mat = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 17, 18, 19, 20},
            {8, 7, 6, 5, 24, 23, 22, 21},
            {12, 11, 10, 9, 28, 27, 26, 25},
            {16, 15, 14, 13, 32, 31, 30, 29},
            {49, 50, 51, 52, 33, 34, 35, 36},
            {56, 55, 54, 53, 40, 39, 38, 37},
            {60, 59, 58, 57, 45, 46, 41, 42},
            {64, 63, 62, 61, 48, 47, 44, 43}};
public static boolean search(int[][] mat, int num) {
    int n = mat.length;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int[] indic = {-1, -1};
    if (num > mat[n - 1][0] || num < mat[0][0]) {
        return false;
    }
    while (n > 1) {
        int minS1 = mat[i][j];
        int maxS1 = mat[(n / 2) - 1 + i][j];
        int minS2 = mat[i][(n / 2) + j];
        int maxS2 = mat[(n / 2) - 1 + i][(n / 2) + j];
        int minS3 = mat[(n / 2) + i][(n / 2) + j];
        int maxS3 = mat[(n - 1) + i][(n / 2) + j];

        int minS4 = mat[(n / 2) + i][j];
        int maxS4 = mat[(n - 1) + i][j];
        checkSquare(num, n, indic, i, j, minS1, minS2, minS3, minS4, maxS1, maxS2, maxS3, maxS4);
        if (indic[0] != -1 && indic[1] != -1) {
            System.out.println("num=" + num);
            System.out.println("row=" + indic[0]);
            System.out.println("col=" + indic[1]);
            return true;
        }
        boolean x = false;
        if (num > maxS2) {
            if (num > maxS3) {
                i += n / 2;
            } else {
                if (n <= mat.length / 2 && i <= (n / 2)) {
                    x = true;
                    i += 1;
                    j += 1;
                } else {
                    if (i >= n / 2 && j < n / 2 && ((i < n) && (j < n))) {
                        i += 1;
                        j += 1;
                    } else {

                        System.out.println(minS1);
                        System.out.println(minS2);
                        System.out.println(minS3);
                        i += 1;
                        j += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (num > maxS1) {
                j += n / 2;
            } else {

                if (num > minS2) {
                    if (j > (mat.length / 2))
                        j = 0;
                    j += 1;
                    x = true;
                } else j += 1;
            }
        }
        if (num == mat[i][j]) {
            System.out.println("num=" + num);
            System.out.println("row=" + i);
            System.out.println("col=" + j);
            return true;
        }
        if (!x)
            n = (n / 2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you worked on this problem for the past few days you should share your results so far. Even if it doesn't work sharing some code that show your attempt is always a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure your `mat` example is such a quadratic array? It does not resemble the description image very well. Were you given this as a correct example or was that your attempt at making one?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the 2D array you have given is correct according to the picture you've provided. All values in a higher quadrant (numbered clock-wise, starting from the top left) need to be bigger than all values in a lower quadrant. And this rule also applies for all sub-arrays until a size of 1x1 is reached. For example:

Element 24 is placed in position 2-1-3, meaning position 3 in the first sub-quadrant of the second main-quadrant.

Likewise, element 19 is placed in position 2-2-1, so after 2-1-3

I hope I understood correctly.

**Edit:**

Here's how I would proceed. I'll let you figure out the missing parts yourself.
First, define a function that returns the quadrant bounds:

```
int[][] getQuadrantBounds(int iMin, int iMax, int jMin, int jMax){...}
```

Let this function return a int[4][4]. It contains the `iMin, iMax, jMin, jMax` for four quadrants.

Then check if the smallest element in the third quadrant is bigger or smaller or equal to `num`. Remember, the smallest element in any quadrant is always at `[jMin][iMin]` or `[iMin][jMin]` depending on your implementation.

After that you know if the element is either in quadrants 1,2 or 3,4. Repeat the process but adapt it for two quadrants. Now you know in which quadrant `num` is.

Of course you did all that in a while loop like:

```
while(iMax - iMin > 0){ 
    int[][] quadrants = getQuadrantBounds(iMin, iMax, jMin, jMax);
    //TODO find first element in third quadrant
    //TODO nested if statements
    //TODO update iMin, iMax, jMin, jMax accordingly inside if statements
}
```

Repeat until found or until the while condition is no longer given.

There's probably a lot of room for improvement but this should give a O(log_2(n)) execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! it seems like mat is really not a good example for the kind of array, but the picture is accurate, so i will make a new mat that meets requirements, still, my code doesn’t cover a given nxn array of this kind ):

Comment: Look at my edit. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static boolean search (int [][] mat, int num)
{
    int size=mat.length;
    int currentQuadrantRow=0;
    int currentQuadrantCol=0;
    int minQ1=mat[0][0];
    int minQ2=mat[0][size/2];
    int minQ3=mat[size/2][size/2];
    int minQ4=mat[size/2][0];
    int maxQ1;
    int maxQ2;
    int maxQ3;
    int maxQ4;
    if (size / 2 == 0)
    {
        maxQ1 = minQ1;
        maxQ2 = minQ2;
        maxQ3=minQ3;
        maxQ4=minQ4;
    }
    else
    {
        maxQ1 = mat[(size/ 2)-1][0];
        maxQ2 = mat[((size/ 2) - 1)][0+(size / 2)];
        maxQ3 = mat[(size - 1)][0+(size / 2)];
        maxQ4 = mat[(size - 1)][0];
    }
    while (size>1)
    {
        if (minQ1 > num) {
            return false;
        } else if (num <= maxQ1) {
            size = size/ 2;
        } else if (minQ2 > num) {
            return false;
        } else if (num <= maxQ2) {
            size = size/ 2;
            currentQuadrantCol = currentQuadrantCol + size;
        } else if (minQ3 > num) {
            return false;
        } else if (num <= maxQ3) {
            size = size/ 2;
            currentQuadrantRow = currentQuadrantRow + size;
            currentQuadrantCol = currentQuadrantCol + size;
        } else if (minQ4 > num) {
            return false;
        } else if (num <= maxQ4) {
            size = size/ 2;
            currentQuadrantRow = currentQuadrantRow + size;
        } else if (num > maxQ4) {
            return false;
        }
        System.out.println(currentQuadrantRow);
        System.out.println(currentQuadrantCol);
        minQ1 = mat[currentQuadrantRow][currentQuadrantCol];
        minQ2 = mat[currentQuadrantRow][currentQuadrantCol+(size / 2)];
        minQ3 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+(size / 2)][currentQuadrantCol+(size / 2)];
        minQ4 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+(size / 2)][currentQuadrantCol];
        if (size / 2 == 0)
        {
            maxQ1 = minQ1;
            maxQ2 = minQ2;
            maxQ3=minQ3;
            maxQ4=minQ4;
        }
        else
        {
            maxQ1 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+((size/ 2) - 1)][currentQuadrantCol];
            maxQ2 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+((size/ 2) - 1)][currentQuadrantCol+(size / 2)];
            maxQ3 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+(size - 1)][currentQuadrantCol+(size / 2)];
            maxQ4 = mat[currentQuadrantRow+(size - 1)][currentQuadrantCol];
        }
    }
    if(mat[currentQuadrantRow][currentQuadrantCol]==num)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please do add details in your answer.